# Getting "TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType" whenever trying to run write_videofile to a clip in moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, moviepy

Example code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
clip.write_videofile('video2.mp4', fps=30)
```

After showing the following messages, showing that the video is being built and written,

```
Moviepy - Building video video2.mp4.
Moviepy - Writing video video2.mp4
```

The following error message occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 300, in write_videofile
    ffmpeg_write_video(self, filename, fps, codec,
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 213, in ffmpeg_write_video
    with FFMPEG_VideoWriter(filename, clip.size, fps, codec = codec,
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 88, in __init__
    '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

This occurs whenever I try to perform `write_videofile` to any kinds of clip in moviepy. It is strange since the exact same code worked for me yesterday, but suddenly not anymore today. Are there any suggestions what the cause is and how to resolve this?

Comment: code works correctly on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 27):

Try upgrading your moviepy package

```
pip install moviepy --upgrade
```

I was facing the same issue with 1.0.0. Upgrading to 1.0.3 fixed that issue.

Comment: Getting exactly this error, but moviepy is already 1.0.3.  What then?  (Ubuntu).

Comment: It's work for me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @sh37211 I had installed already 1.0.3 and execute the command again and it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your kernel if you're on a jupyter notebook!

Comment: Yes, this probably comes down to restarting the kernel so that `moviepy`-`ffmpeg` bindings are available at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

My problem presented as:

```
---> 88     '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
     89     '-an', '-i', '-'
     90 ]
     91 if audiofile is not None:
     92     cmd.extend([
     93         '-i', audiofile,
     94         '-acodec', 'copy'
     95     ])

TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

It would save the MP3 file, but failed when writing the MP4 file.

I fixed this problem with:

```
pip install ffmpeg --upgrade
```

Comment: Upgrading FFMPEG worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem (even with version `1.0.3` of moviepy) while trying to display the video clip in a Jupyter notebook using `clip.ipython_display`.

In my case, the problem was caused by the FFmpeg version detected by moviepy which was `ffmpeg-imageio` (whatever that is).

As described on the [installation page](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html) of moviepy, you can basically do two things:

- Pass the location of the FFmpeg binary you want to use using the `FFMPEG_BINARY` environment variable.
- Edit the file `config_defaults.py` and set the variable to the location of the binary there.

In both cases, you need to restart the process/kernel for the effects to take place. In my case, I found the `config_defaults.py` inside my virtual env folder (on Linux) at:

```
<project dir>/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/config_defaults.py
```

Answer (score 4):

If upgrade your moviepy package is not work for you

Try downgrade the decorator package

`pip install --upgrade decorator==4.4.2`

Comment: I had to try a few different decorator versions, I ended up settling on the earliest one allowed by moviepy 1.0.3 which was decorator 4.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem, even with 1.0.3. In my case, I got it to work by reinstalling ffmpeg over Homebrew with `brew reinstall ffmpeg`.

Comment: Confirm solution is working (MacOS 10.15.5 Catalina), had the same issue. `pip install moviepy --upgrade` did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late but for the sake of someone else:

If you have *just* installed

```
pip3 install moviepy
```

make sure to restart the kernel if you are on a Juypter notebook,
otherwise you will keep getting:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case

`pip uninstall ffmpeg moviepy`

`pip install moviepy`

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code/commands in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution

Answer (score 1):

I had this error using Python 3.10, and it appears to be fixed by downgrading to Python 3.9.

(Using MoviePy 1.0.3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on mac.

```
brew reinstall ffmpeg
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds silly, but Python code file was in folder with long path. Moved file to shorter one and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 version 22h2, x64 system, Ryzen 7
here is some information on my conifguration

- jupyter : 1.0
- jupyterlab: 3.5.3
- python: 3.9.16
- moviepy: 1.0.3
- ffmpeg: 1.4
- pygame: 2.3
- decorator: 4.4.2

running through jupyterlab

in order to not get the "TypeError must be a real number" error, I had to pip install these specific specific versions of the packages.

- pygame not installed: error
- ffmpeg not installed: error
- pygame not installed: error
- decorator older or newer than 4.4.2: error
- python 3.10 : error

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be related to your Python version, as I had the same issue with Python 3.6.13, Moviepy 1.0.3, and Pygame 2.4.0. However, when I switched to Python 3.8.16 and reinstalled Moviepy and Pygame with the same versions, it worked well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was not with MoviePy or FFMPEG, but with the decorator version. Only after downgrading it to 4.0.2 I could make it to work.

Try downgrade the decorator package

```
pip install --upgrade decorator==4.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but the only solution worked for me is forced reinstalling dependencies. (Mine was python 3.11.5 and moviepy 1.03)

```
pip install moviepy --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Since anything can go wrong in its dependencies from ffmpeg to decorator, forced reinstalling helped me. but careful since it may change your numpy and other's version since you may need it for other things.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have met the same problem.
Then I checked my moviepy version: 1.0.3. I checked my ffmpeg version: 1.4. I updated decorator version: 5.5.1 -> 4.4.2.

```
pip install --upgrade decorator==4.4.2
```

It worked well.

Answer (score -1):

I just replaced the argument in the function:
(file ffmpeg_writer.py for me it in C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io)

```
def ffmpeg_write_video(clip, filename, fps, codec="libx264", bitrate=None, ...
```

with:

```
def ffmpeg_write_video(clip, filename, fps, codec="libx264", bitrate=0.0, ...
```

Answer (score -1):

for me installing pygame corrected the problem

```
pip install pygame
```

as stated here : https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html

Answer (score -1):

**try:** fps=final_clip.fps

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
clip.write_videofile('video2.mp4', fps=final_clip.fps)
```

Comment: Where did you get final_clip?